# Hello World Angular Example

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading and doing my first excercies on Angular.

After a while I'm stuck on this. Simple "Hello World" is not working.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
                <body>
                        <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
                                <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
                        </div>
                <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
                <!-- Angular -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
                myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.greeting = 'hey!!';
                }]);
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show your view code. Do you include your ng-app="myApp"  in that?, and do you include your ng-controller="GreetingController"  in som of your view?

Comment: You need to specify what "not working" means.. but it seems that perhaps you're referring to `{{greeting.text}}` rendering a blank. Seems like a minor typo - did you just mean to do `{{greeting}}`?

Comment: thats right!!, you should use greeting as well. Thats data binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `<p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>` should be `<p>{{greeting}}, world </p>`.